# Need to make some Free space VG PE Size

Tags: redhat, lvm

I want to add 150GB space in Free PE /Size.

How can I accomplish this?

```
[root@localhost ~]# vgdisplay rhel01
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               rhel01
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               204.89 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              52452
  Alloc PE / Size       52452 / 204.89 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
```

Comment: To add space, add a physical volume. Alternatively, if possible increase the size of the physical volumes and run `pvresize`.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `pvs` `lvs` and `lsblk`. How do you plan to add more space? expanding the LVM PV or by adding another PV to the same VG?

Answer (score 0):

If you have another disk you can do:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdX
```

Or you could add more space to your pv in case you have it available:

```
pvresize /dev/sdXY
```

Then extend the VG:

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/VGNAME/LVNAME
```